# Powershell invoke-webrequest for powershell 2.0

Tags: powershell

I have created a script in powershell 5.0 that retrieves a data in the website and puts it inside a file. The following code works on windows 7 and higher since they all have .net framework 5.0. Now I was informed that i needs to run on lower windows OS such as XP. powershells in XP is 2.0, and microsoft already ended XP support. I need a powershell 2.0 code that would behaves the same as the code I have written in 5.0:

```
$number = 1000
$startdate = 2017-01-05
$enddate = 2017-01-11
invoke-webrequest -Uri http://192.168.1.1/form/Download?uid=$number"&"sdate=$startdate"&"edate=$enddate -OutFile D:\Timekeeping\dtr\data.dat -PassThru
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no direct cmdlet for an alternative:

But you can use the below:

```
$URI1 = "<your uri>"

$password = ConvertTo-SecureString $wpassword -AsPlainText -Force
$credential = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential ($wusername, $password)

$request = [System.Net.WebRequest]::Create($URI1)
$request.ContentType = "application/xml"
$request.Method = "POST"
$request.Credentials = $credential

# $request | Get-Member  for a list of methods and properties 

try
{
    $requestStream = $request.GetRequestStream()
    $streamWriter = New-Object System.IO.StreamWriter($requestStream)
    $streamWriter.Write($body)
}

finally
{
    if ($null -ne $streamWriter) { $streamWriter.Dispose() }
    if ($null -ne $requestStream) { $requestStream.Dispose() }
}

$res = $request.GetResponse()
```

So basically we are using the Dot Net Class for it :

```
$request = [System.Net.WebRequest]::Create("$url")
$request.ContentType='application/json; charset=utf-8'
$request.GetResponse()
```

You can parse it stream wise :

```
$ResponseStream = $Response.GetResponseStream()
$ReadStream = New-Object System.IO.StreamReader $ResponseStream
$Data=$ReadStream.ReadToEnd()
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: @joey: we are not a free script giving service.. You have to try yourself. We are here to help you out

Comment: @Joey: You can store the result of the invoke in a variable and you can out-file it to a text file like 
`$a | Out-File D:\output.txt -Force`